# How can I use different environment variables in a npm package based on the consuming application?

Tags: npm, environment-variables

I am creating a library of Vue Custom Elements in an npm package. Each component makes requests to my own API. I am currently hard coding the base URL for the API in the released version of the package. This is a problem because there are 3 different versions of the API that I need to use depending on where the package is being used: a localhost API, a Test/QA API, and a Production API.

Is it possible for the consuming application of a package to control which base URL the package will use in its requests? I need some way of letting the package know if it should use Prod, Test, or dev/local environment.

I have tried:

- passing values with `process.env` but these are not shared between the consuming application and the package;
- using relative URLs for the requests within the package, but this won't work in other products, and the API base URL is different than my web URL;
- I could set up different packages for different environments but I am trying to avoid maintaining different packages.
- I could pass the base url as a prop to each component, although I am trying to avoid this as it would be a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Why not just pass it as an argument, so that the consumer can also decide how to represent that environment in their application: `something.whatever({ environment: process.env.NODE_ENV })`, or `something.whatever({ baseUrl: someUrl })`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you expand on this? My npm package is a library of vue components. I'm not sure that I am able to pass arguments as there is no scripts that the consuming application is directly calling.

Comment: That would be useful context to share in the question; I am not familiar with the Vue ecosystem, so can't give specifics on patterns there, but in React you might use a [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) to hold specific configuration for all the components your library supplies.